# Heroku not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have successfully pushed my heroku app. However, when I open the URL it says not found. Any reasons why it cannot render anything.

```
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

And when I open the link it shows

```
Not Found.
```

I am using node and react

Comment: Might I ask are you using ExpressJS or something else like `create-react-app`?

Comment: @FelixFong yes using EXPRESSJS but not using create-react-app. using build

Comment: Are you using the `process.env.PORT` to define the running Express app? because within the Heroku environment, Heroku will automatically and dynamically define a active and running port for the application.